# How to mark a cucumber test with a callback as pending in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumberjs

Is it possible to mark a cucumber test in Node as pending, so we have upcoming features specified but avoid failing automated tests?

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.Given(/^Some future scenario$/, function(callback) {
    callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the documentation is very unclear but I found out that you can pass a couple of parameters to the callback, and passing `null` as the first will mark it as a pending test.

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.Given(/^Some future scenario$/, function(callback) {
    callback(null, 'reason why pending');
    }
}
```

Hope it saves someone else some time!